# C# interface and abstract class

Tags: c#, class, polymorphism

I have defined an `interface`, an `abstract` class that implements that interface and a class that derives from the abstract class. I need the `interface` because I am using a dynamic loader to implement the plugins and I created an abstract class to implement a few things that all plugins will have.

Now I want to implement a class-wide string as a name. What I created is this:

```
public interface IDevicePlugin {
    string name { get; }
}

abstract public class DevicePlugin : IDevicePlugin {
    abstract public string name { get; }
}


public class somePlugin : DevicePlugin, IDevicePlugin {
    public override string name {
        get {
            return "my name";
        }
    }
}
```

But this gives me the error "cannot override because 'name' is not a property'. If I remove the `override`, it says it is hiding the inherited member 'name'.

How do I correctly implement this?

Comment: no *any* error on this, what framework do you use ?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010, .NET 3.5 Client profile.

Comment: @Bart have you tried the code you posted ***in a separate/clean project*** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't error for me, but... I suspect that this is because you are re-implementing the interface. Drop the `, IDevicePlugin` in `somePlugin`:

```
public class somePlugin : DevicePlugin {
    public override string name {
        get { return "my name"; }
    }
}
```

It inherits the interface from the parent class.

Comment: @BartFriederichs what compiler / tools / etc are you using? As stated, that doesn't actually error for me... I am assuming it is something from a 3rd-party plugin, or there is something you haven't told us about. Does the code you've posted, **in a separate project**, error for you?

Comment: You're right. It was an out-of-sync assembly. I was messing up my projects. Thanks though for the tip about the interface being inherited from the parent class.

Comment: @BartFriederichs For me too. What tools or compiler? What options for compilation?

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2010, .NET 3.5, I have a solution with multiple projects. The DevicePlugin class and the IDevicePlugin interface are in one project, the somePlugin in another. I didn't actually recompile the DevicePlugin and IDevicePlugin, making the other project using old (wrong) code.